# Does recompiling a compiler has effects on the compiled code?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, system-administration

I have to install without root access some software (the gromacs simulation package) on a cluster server, on which jobs can be sent through slurm. I only have direct access to the front-end machine, and the home directory is shared among all the servers and front-end. I had to manually build and install locally:

- gcc 4.8
- automake, autoconf, cmake
- openmpi
- lapack libs
- gromacs

Right now, I have installed all of this only on the front-end, which is an older Intel Xeon machine. The production servers have new AMD processor instead. This is my question: in order to achieve optimal performance, which parts of the aforementioned stack should be recompiled on the production servers? I guess it would make much sense to rebuild the final software (gromacs) and maybe the lapack libs, because of the different instruction sets and processor architecture, but I'm not exactly sure whether it would make any sense to rebuild the compiler or other parts of the system. Hence the question: does using a compiler (and the associated libraries) which have been built on a different machine result in higher execution times for the generated binaries?
In general, I'd expect a compiler to produce the same binaries if given the same output, so the answer would be no; but what about the libraries (as libstdc++) which have been compiled together with the compiler on the other machine?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to optimize gromacs (parallel molecular dynamics code), you can forget about recompiling the compileror the compilation tools: that's useless.

You should go after and check for optimizations. For Intel CPU using the Intel C compiler makes a difference. It's possible you observe some gains with AMDs as well.

Another alternative is to use the [Portland Group compiler](http://www.pgroup.com).

Regarding MPI, you need to be sure it's customized for your interconnect (for example, if you have infiniband, avoid to use the TCP standard version).

regarding lapack libraries, you need to install optimized lapack ([ACML](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/cpu-development/amd-core-math-library-acml/) for AMDs, [MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) for Intels. You can use with very good performance GOTO or ATLAS blas - they are included in many linux distros).

You have not mentioned FFT: they are indeed important for electromagnetics (Ewald summations) in the simulations: FFTW here is a good choice. You need to install the correct version for the processor or compile it on the target processor, because it performs a sort of "auto-tuning" in the compilation process.

Going below than this (tools, compilers) make no difference on the produced executables.

Comment: Thanks! Great hearing feedback from an expert user. I usually have gromacs build its own FFTW, and assume that it knows what it's doing (or better yet, the gromacs authors do :) ). I had considered the Intel compilers, but on the gromacs installation instructions they claim that with the latest AMD processors gcc should be faster. However, I can give them a try. I will also consider installing the specialized lapack libraries.

Comment: that's I didn't remember! (about fftw - It was time ago last time I did it). In this case you should perform the Gromacs compilation itself on the target machine - in a batch script sent in the queuing system (or ask the sys to do it.... I know I know - I was a HPC user support specialist)

Comment: Yep, thanks we did just that using an interactive shell. That fftw autobuild feature is relatively recent (gromacs 4.6 onward), and quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

Building the GCC compiler already involves a four-stage bootstrap process, one of whose purposes is to QA the compiler by ensuring the last two stages produce the same output. So there is no reason to believe that a fifth stage will have any effect at all.